# Correct sequence in a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, iteration

In R, I am trying to build the matrix 'pi' through an inductive process, I've tried the following code:

```
lambda<-0.2    #Tuning Parameter
T<-521

pi<-matrix(0,ncol=3,nrow=T-1)   #Empty matrix for portfolio pi, 3 columns for 3 stocks, T-1 time periods
pi[1,]<-1/3    #starting weights: Equal Weighted Portfolio

V<-matrix(0,ncol=1,nrow=T-1)    #Empty vector for portfolio relative value process
V[1] <- 1         #Starting wealth = $1

FE<-matrix(0,ncol=1,nrow=T-1) #Emptry vector for free energy at each time point

K<-matrix(0,ncol=1,nrow=T-1)  #Empty vector for kappa (convex parameter)
#will only be T-2 values for K=kappa, ignore the first to keep index the same as other variables

for( i in (1:T-1)){

  V[i+1]<-sum(pi[i,]*(1+r[i,]))/Vmu[i+1]

  FE[i]<-log(V[i+1]) - log(V[i]) - sum(pi[i,]*(mu[i+1,]/mu[i,]))

  K[i+1]<-min( 1 , lambda*FE[i]/abs( sum(1+(log(pi[i,]/mu[i+1]))) ) )                              

  pi[i+1,]<-pi[i,] + K[i+1]*(mu[i+1,]-pi[i,])
}
```

the code isn't working, and I am just wondering if the for loop works in the following steps:

1. find V[2] then FE [2] then K[2] then pi[2] then repeat for 3,4,...

(which is what I want)

or is it doing
2. find V[2], V[3],...........V[T] then FE[2],FE[3],....,FE[T],......etc

(which is not what I want.)

If it is doing it the second way, how can I adjust it so that it follows the first method?

Comment: `pi[1,]<-1/3` is not a correct assignment.

Comment: @Pascal could you explain why? it does what I want, which is set the first element of the 3 columns to 1/3

Comment: I don't think it really works. At least, not on my R.

Comment: @Pascal : example b<-matrix(0,ncol=3,nrow=5),  b[1,]<-1/3, View(b) works fine for me..

Comment: It is not what you wrote. You wrote `pi<-matrix(0,ncol=3,nrow=T-1)` As `T` stands for `TRUE` (because not defined in your post), `T-1` gives `0`.

Comment: @Pascal oh my apologies, I was trying to cut down on the code I provided here for clarity, fixed now

Comment: In your `for` loop the inner pair of parentheses is superfluous as it is, and it is almost certainly misplaced. Try replacing the part `for(i in (1:T-1))` with `for(i in 1:(T-1)) `